# Restructuring of package

Tags: java, package, java-package

Hi I am trying to restructure the package but with no luck. Suppose there are multiple packages in a project like:

```
main.java.com.wms.package1
main.java.com.wms.package2
main.java.com.wms.package3
```

I want to restructure it in the below format:

```
main.java
  com.wms.package1
  com.wms.package2
  com.wms.package3
```

Think of it this way there are 50 packages that start with main.java. So I want to make main.java as main package and the 50 packages under the main.java package
How do I do this?

Comment: You don't. The 2 structures you're showing are exactly the sam just displayed differently.

Comment: Java file can have single package. Do you mean import statement?

Comment: Main.java is not part of packagename i think.

Comment: There are java classes inside package 1 , it is referring to classes inside package 2 and package 3 by importing, but the classes inside packages are without main.java

Comment: Like jens said main.java is not part of package name

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `package com.main;

import com.wms.package1;
import com.wms.package2;
import com.wms.package3;
public class Main {
 
}`

Comment: change source folder to `main.java` (or better `main/java`), change all `package` statements to remove the `main.java.` part, change all relevant imports to remove `main.java.`

Comment: Think of it this way there are 50 packages all starting with main.java.So i want to remove main.java.outside as main package and 50 packages under main.java package. Someone has any solution??

Comment: @PramodBhat You sure that 50 packages start with "main.java"? Do the sourcefiles contain a `package main.java....` at the beginning?

Comment: Yes there are 50 packages that start with main.java. I would have posted the screenshot but its confidential

Comment: @PramodBhat Well, then first: poor you to be in a position to deal with such code! If possible I'd suggest a refactoring then. Basically by convention package names usually start with a TLD and then your company's domain. If that's not possible, look for the options of you IDE. Probably you can hide common prefixes in the package list or something.

Answer (score 1):

**one:** "main.java" ist not part of the package names.

**two:** Although the path-like appearance of package names may trick you into thinking that, Java packages are *not* hierarchical. That means `foo.bar` is *not* a child of `foo`. If you want the list of packages to be displayed in a certain style, see if your IDE supports that style!

**three:** If your source files *really* contain the line `package main.java...` a refactoring should be considered. If that is not possible, follow option **two**!